# Detect when UITableViewCell goes out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I detect when a UITableViewCell derived object gets removed from a table and into the cache?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement either of the following methods.  When removed from the table, superview will become nil.  When added back to the table, superview will be set to the table view.

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview;
- (void)didMoveToSuperview;
```

Also see

```
- (void)prepareForReuse;
```

Comment: It does not work on iOS 6.x. I have implemented all 3 methods, willMoveToSuperview and didMoveToSuperview get called only first time I scroll the tableview. prepareForReuse get called every time I scroll the table view. So it is not possible to determine if the cell has been removed from the table view with first 2 methods. The 3. method get called while reusing it and not removing from the tableview.

Answer (score 4):

after ios 6.0 you have the following method of UITableViewDelegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a table view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it appears or disappears.
```

Comment: I think you mean >= iOS6.