# iOS callback when uitableviewcell gets destroyed

Tags: ios, uitableview

As a user scrolls up and down in an uitableview cells get destroyed and created.

Is there a way to detect when a cell is going to be or has been destroyed?

Comment: Maybe you should put your question in the context of what you really want to accomplish.  My problem with answering it is that there's no guarantee of the cells being destroyed when they scroll away; they're often cached for re-use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330735/detect-when-uitableviewcell-goes-out-of-scope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that by "getting destroyed" you actually are referring to a cell getting reused, simply implement `prepareForReuse` within your `UITableViewCell` derived class.

**prepareForReuse**

Prepares a reusable cell for reuse by the table view's delegate.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

**Discussion**

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse
>   identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For
>   performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that
>   are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection
>   state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
>   should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell
>   object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is
>   not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke
>   the superclass implementation.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
See Also
– initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:
  @property reuseIdentifier
Declared In
UITableViewCell.h

Comment: Correct. The implications of this are important. The `prepareForReuse` message is sent when the cell is coming out of the pool, not when it's done being displayed. This means it cannot be relied upon to release heavyweight resources retained by the cell implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Without going into the implications of suitability or performance, another option might be to periodically check what cells remain visible, using the visibleCells method of the UITableView class:

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```

As per the documentation:

> Returns an array containing UITableViewCell objects, each representing a visible cell in the receiving table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UITableViewCell` and override it's `dealloc` method.

Any good reason to do it assuming you are reusing the cells to save the resources ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to intercept is part of the internal implementation of UITableView and how it manages its cells.  While there are ways in which you can attempt to intercept such behavior, I would suggest that you avoid using them, as there is no guarantee that future implementations of UITableView will maintain this behavior.

It would be better in cases such as this to consider a different approach: be it design and implement your own table class, or change your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, cells aren't destroyed when the leave the screen. However there are some things you can do, to track related actions, depending on what you are trying to do.

First there is a delegate message:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is called before a cell enters the screen. Another possibility is the already stated prepareForReuse method of a cell.

Another approach would be: Try and override willMoveToSuperview: or any other of the related methods. I am not sure if this is fired after the cell becomes invisible, but it might work.

Best regards,
Michael